# JQUERY code not working after array is called

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create an array called NAME. For some reason, the code works for the alert('test1') but the code stops working for alert('test2')

```
$(document).on('submit','form',function()
{                       
    $('input',this).each(function()
    {
        NAME = $(this).attr('name').split('-');

        for(COUNT=0;COUNT<NAME.length;COUNT++)
        {
            TYPE = NAME[COUNT];

            if(TYPE == 'SOMETHING')
            {                   
                DO STUFF
            }
        }

        alert("test1");
    });

    alert("test2");
});
```

I narrowed it down to the following. After deleting this, it alert('test2') is called.

```
NAME = $(this).attr('name').split('-');
```

Whats wrong here?

Comment: Check your error console. There may be an `<input>` element without a `name` attribute, and `split()` cannot be applied to `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks! I understand now :) I thought it would just give an empty array and pass through. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Frederic,

```
if ($(this).attr('name')) {
    // attribute exists
} else {
    // attribute does not exist
}
```

Comment: Alas, your answer is incorrect. `undefined`, `null`, `0` and the empty string `""` all evaluate to `false` in a boolean context. Attributes that are present but do not have a value will make `attr()` return the empty string. Your condition should be `if ($(this).attr('name') != undefined)` or even `if ($(this).attr('name') !== undefined)` if you want to be extra-strict.